# JsonDeserialize throws JSON parse error on request in Kotlin

Tags: java, json, kotlin, jackson

I am trying to use Jackson's JsonDeserialize in Kotlin, but I am having problems setting up the data classes. I get the following error when I throw a request to the controller.

> JSON parse error: Instantiation of [simple type, class co.com.bancodebogota.customer.accounts.entities.Customer] value failed for JSON property identificationNumber due to missing (therefore NULL) value for creator parameter identificationNumber which is a non-nullable type

My data classes looks like this -->

```
data class BalanceByAccountRq @JsonCreator constructor(
    @JsonProperty("customer") var customer: Customer,
    @JsonProperty("account") var account: Account,
    @JsonProperty("ipAddress") var ipAddress: String,
    @JsonProperty("bankId") var bankId: String)

data class Customer @JsonCreator constructor(
    @JsonProperty("identificationNumber") @JsonDeserialize(using = AsymmetricDeserializerString::class) var identificationNumber: String,
    @JsonProperty("identificationType") var identificationType: String)

data class Account @JsonCreator constructor(
    @JsonProperty("accountId") var accountId: String,
    @JsonProperty("accountType") var accountType: String)
```

If I remove the JsonProperty does not make any difference

Has anybody used this in kotlin? Am I missing something?

This is the application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = arrayOf("co.com.adl", "co.com.bancodebogota"))
@EnableConfigurationProperties
class PbBbogAvalProductBalanceDetailApplication

    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        SpringApplication.run(PbBbogAvalProductBalanceDetailApplication::class.java, *args)
    }

    @Bean
    @Throws(NoSuchAlgorithmException::class, NoSuchPaddingException::class)
    fun asymmetricCryptography(): AsymmetricCryptography {
        return AsymmetricCryptography();
    }
```

And the controller:

```
@PostMapping("/balance")
fun getBalanceByAccount(@RequestBody @Valid rq: BalanceByAccountRq, resultOfValidation: BindingResult): ResponseEntity<BalanceByAccountRs> {
    System.out.println(rq);
    if (resultOfValidation.hasErrors()) {
        var fieldErrors : List<FieldError> = resultOfValidation.getFieldErrors();
        throw RequiredValidator(ERROR_PARAMETROS_DE_ENTRADA, fieldErrors);
    } else {
        return gbba.getBalanceByAccount(rq);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Payload:

```
{
    "customer": {
        "identificationNumber": "80026300",
        "identificationType": "CC"
    },
    "account": {
        "accountId": "8929932",
        "accountType":"SDA"
    },
    "bankId": "0052",
    "ipAddress": "192.168.0.1"
}
```

In dev profile does not decrypt, therefore the parameter is not encrypted in this payload. This works fine in a java8 microservice

Comment: Could you also provide a `JSON` `payload`?

Comment: sure, check the edit please

Comment: I see you also use custome deserialiser - `AsymmetricDeserializerString`. It also could generate a problem. Could you please show it as well?

Comment: your `JSON` `payload` looks fine. I think it could be linked with `Kotlin` language specification and `not-null` parameters. Take a look on https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/issues/87

Comment: Jackon requires by default an no-arg constructor for each class. This constructor does not have to be public. Your model classes have only one constructor that takes multiple arguments.

Comment: @Robert but kotlin requires at least one arg constructor for data classes, I am confused